# Is there a way to preview attached videos in email in Outlook 2007 without saving it?

Tags: video, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In some case some email received with attached video and I search for a way to allow me to preview it in Outlook 2007 without needing to save it as it preview word or excel files embedded in mail .. Could any help me in that ?

Answer (score 2):

This site contains some preview handlers for outlook 2007. 
http://www.azarfamily.org/previewhandlersforwindowsxp/

Comment: is there any more easy in installation one ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your comment.

Comment: Sorry,I mean i search for one that can be installed easily , as what i found in the above link is difficult in installation

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have to be clear about "difficult". Make sure you are running the installer with admin privileges.